# Update part of a value in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-table

I have a table "users" in mysql with around 2K records. In the table, there is a field "status". The status can be of 2 to 3 words. In few status, at the end, there is a space followed by an asterisk mark. I want to remove the space and asterisk. Please help me with a query to update the values. Here are some examples

```
Not smiling
always laughing *
never jumps *
keep it up
oh my god *
```

I want to change this to:

```
Not smiling
always laughing
never jumps
keep it up
oh my god
```

SELECT * FROM users WHERE ?????? (How to write the condition?)

EDIT:
Thanks everyone for the answers. Can someone shed some light on which answer is the best considering replacing 2000+ records, utilization of computer resources, memory, efficiency etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this single line query to find and replace only the records with * in status

```
update users set status = replace(status, ' *', '') where instr(status, ' *') > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use following syntax/command to search and replace *

```
update users set status = replace(status, ' *', '') where instr(status, ' *') > 0;
```

This will find the string with *  and replace without *.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

how About with query Replace

```
 Update user 
set column = REPLACE(column, '*','')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
$sql='SELECT id,status FROM users WHERE status like %* %';

while( $rs=$conn->query($sql) )
{
   $newStatus = str_replace(' *',rs[1]);
    $sqlUpdate="UPDATE users SET status =$newStatus WHERE id=rs[0]";

    if($conn->query($sqlUpdate) === false) {
        trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sqlUpdate. ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run below query:

update users
set status=RTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status, '*', 1))
where status like '%*'